# Preview files selected from input file SOLVE

Tags: javascript, jsp, for-loop, preview, file-io

I've got the next code:

```
            function PreviewImage() {
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            var documentos = document.getElementById("uploadImage");
            var tamanio = documentos.files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < tamanio; i++) {
                document.write("-"+i);
                oFReader = new FileReader();
                oFReader.readAsDataURL(documentos.files[i]);
                oFReader.onload = function(event) {
                    document.write("+"+i);
                    document.getElementById("uploadPreview"+i).src = event.target.result;
                };                   
            }          
        }
```

This read the files from the input uploadImage. I want to preview the images on tags which id="uploadPreviewX". It works great when I don't use for loop. I printed "i" for testing, the first impression is correct: -0-1-2 - ... - (tamanio-1), the problem is the second, then prints tamanio tamanio times. For example, if you select 4 files the output is: -0-1-2-3 +4 +4 +4 +4. And therefore I can only preview a img where id = uploadPreview4. 
What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE SOLVE**
After reading some documentation about Javascript closure inside loops... I could do it.

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

  `function PreviewImage() {
              var funcs = [];
              var documentos = document.getElementById("uploadImage");
              var tamanio = documentos.files.length;
              for (var i = 0; i < tamanio; i++) {
                  funcs[i] = (function(index) {
                      return function(event) {
                          document.getElementById("uploadPreview" + index).src = event.target.result;
                      };
                  })(i);
              }
              var oFReader = new FileReader();
              for (var k = 0; k < tamanio; k++) {
                  oFReader = new FileReader();
                  oFReader.readAsDataURL(documentos.files[k]);
                  oFReader.onload = funcs[k];

              }

          }`

Thank you

Comment: Can you create a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Yes, thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=HppKS6Bg4s @RahilWazir

Comment: JavaScript has function scope not for scope. All items use the same `i` variable. This is the closure loop problem.

Comment: ok, I'm gonna try it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks, after of a lot information about closure I could do it.